# Call scala function from stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, scala, stored-procedures

I wan to call a normal scala function from the stored procedure. Is is possible??

My scala class is:

````
class ClassExp(implicit db: Database, futureAwaitDuration: FiniteDuration) {
  def getData(id: String): Seq[String] = {
    val query =
      sql"select data from table"
        .as[Seq[String]]
    Await.result(db.run(query), futureAwaitDuration)
  }
}```


Stored procedure is:
````

procedure.sql
data AS (

```
**call getData() ??**
select data from table
```

),```

Is is possible to call getData() instead of writing the query in stored procedure?

Comment: If I understood your question correctly - then no, it's not possible, as database knows nothing about you application and functions in it. However, maybe your goal can be achieved by some other means?

Comment: What could be the other means , i do not want to create a separate procedure for the query though.What could be the other options?

Comment: Running everything from scala? It's hard to advice not knowing what your goal is, but if you're trying to do some "get, check result and then insert", you can try writing it in a single query. Or just run two or three queries from scala code.

Comment: If i understand you correctly you mean  convert that is in procedure.sql to scala?